# How do dictionary lookups work in IronRuby?

Tags: ironruby

I have this line of IronPython code:

```
Traits['Strength'].Score + Traits['Dexterity'].Score
```

Traits is defined as such:

```
Dim m_Traits As New Dictionary(Of String, Trait)
scope.SetVariable("Traits", m_Traits)
```

I would like to translate the IronPython code into IronRuby, but I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby (and IronRuby), variables must begin with a lowercase letter. Therefore, just change the `Traits` variable to `traits` to make your code works:

```
var engine = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateEngine();
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("traits", traits);

dynamic result = engine.Execute("traits['Strength'].Score + traits['Dexterity'].Score", scope);
```

(this code works, I checked).

By the way, creating a variable that starts with a capital letter makes it a constant (that's how Ruby works) and adding a constant to the scope is done in a slightly different way.

Comment: That would certainly explain the rather odd error message I was seeing. Thanks.